# Django save tuple of string unexpectedly

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm updating data in django, but the string data becomes tuple string when saved in the database.

```py
@api_view(["POST"])
def cate_edit(req):
    if not req.user.is_staff:
        return HttpResponseNotFound()
    data=jsonload(req.body)
    if not has(data,["id","title","other_title","introduction"]):
        return HttpResponseForbidden()
    id=toNumber(data["id"])
    if id==None:
        return HttpResponseForbidden()
    if id==0:
        c=Category(
            title=data["title"],
            other_title=data["other_title"],
            introduction=data["introduction"]
        )
        c.save()
        return HttpResponse(c.id)
    else:
        c=get_object_or_404(Category,id=id)
        c.title = data["title"],
        c.other_title = data["other_title"],
        c.introduction = data["introduction"]
        c.save()
        return HttpResponse(c.id)
```

The problem happened in the final `else`, I can make sure the data is a valid and normal dict, such as
`{'id': 1, 'title': '1', 'other_title': '2', 'introduction': '3'}`
but after this save process, the data in database is

```
title: "('1',)"
other_title:"('2',)"
introduction: '3'
```

introduction is correct actually.

Additionally, here is the model of category

```py
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    other_title = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True,null=True,upload_to=file_path)
    introduction = models.TextField(default="",blank=True)
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Thanks

Update:
It's cool to use query and `update`, but why above situation happens? I used to do like that but works fine.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You have commas at the end of your assignments.

```
c.title = data[“title”],
```

Should be:

```
c.title = data[“title”]
```

Comment: Wow, dumb error, but at least 6 man faced this, thanks!

Comment: problem of copy and paste